# How do i make the <p> text go down instead of going out the div

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a problem with my cards slider the `<p>` tag keeps going out but i want it to do down in order to fit the whole text for long descriptions how would i go about that?

If you see when i use long text the text ends up getting out the divider but instead i want it be kept inside

I tried using `word-wrap: break-word;` but it doesn't work for me

```css
div.scroll-container {
  background-color: #7289da;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

  .card {
    float: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;   
  padding: 10px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 525px;
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
height: 200px;
}

  .container p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container" id="cardslist">
    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineernjifnnjknhbgvfdfcgvhbjnkmmnbgvfd</p>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS property `white-space: nowrap` on `div.scroll-container` prevents line wrapping on whitespaces. Mozilla has a nice [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) about that CSS property.

One possible fix is to explicitly set it back to `normal` for your `container` class.

As your dummy content has a quite long word, it will still overflow.
Using `word-wrap: break-word;` on the `container` class will fix that problem as well.

EDIT: as pointed out by @j08691 in the comments:

> Adding vertical-align: top to .card will bring them back into alignment

Here is your code with the updated parts:

```css
div.scroll-container {
  background-color: #7289da;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

  .card {
    float: none; 
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;   
  padding: 10px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 525px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
height: 200px;
}

  .container p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container" id="cardslist">
    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineernjifnnjknhbgvfdfcgvhbjnkmmnbgvfd</p>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="card">
  <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding vertical-align: top to .card will bring them back into alignment

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using `white-space: nowrap;` on the `.scrollable` parent element.  If you remove that and set `word-break: break-word;` on `.card` your text will properly wrap.

However this breaks your layout since you were obviously relying on the `nowrap` to make multiple elements fit on the same line.

Try using a flexbox layout. It's much simpler and requires less code

```css
.scroll-container {
  background-color: #7289da;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
  /*Flexbox setup!*/
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  /*float: none; 
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  height: 525px;*/
  
  padding: 10px;
  width: 375px;
  
  /* Added */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  word-break: break-word; 
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
}

  .container p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container" id="cardslist">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineernjifnnjknhbgvfdfcgvhbjnkmmnbgvfd</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="icon.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also causes the cards to "wrap" (i..e no longer be displayed side by side, but one below the other). Not sure if that's what OP wants.

Comment: ok, see my updated answer. It's not a good idea to rely on `nowrap` to force elements to stay on the same line

Comment: Not what i was looking for really, i want the cardsto scroll horixontally

Comment: ah ok, i wasn't aware they they did that in the first place, sorry! I've updated it again, now it uses flexbox and scroll horizontally